# tabnavigator and stacknavigator problem-you should only render one navigator

Tags: reactjs, native, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

### Its My App.js

I want to use stack navigator while not logged, then tabnavigator in sıgnIn Page

```
const AppNavigator=createStackNavigator({

    SıgnIn:{screen:SıgnIn},
    Welcome:{screen:Welcome},
    SıgnUp:{screen:SıgnUp},
    ForgetPassword:{screen:ForgetPassword},


});
```

### Its My App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {


    render() {

        return (
         <AppNavigator></AppNavigator>
        );
    }
}
```

### Its my SıgnIn page

```
const  AppTabNavigator = TabNavigator({
    HomeTab:{screen:HomeTab},
    Search:{screen:Search},
    AddMedia:{screen:AddMedia},
    Followers:{screen:Followers},
    Profile:{screen:Profile},
},
```

It says you should only render one navigator

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using some boolean like `isAuthenticated` to conditionally render your Navigator. You can use the ternary operator to do something like this in `App.js`:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                { isAuthenticated ? <AppNavigator/> : <AppTabNavigator/> }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```